# Weird UIPageViewController sliding behavior with Aspect Fill image mode

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, autolayout, uipageviewcontroller

I just created a `UIPageViewController` with page content view controller that consists of single `ImageView` and a `Button`. It works almost flawlessly, but it has a major issue when I try to slide through the views in vertical view only, with Aspect Fill mode set for my `ImageView` (which is pretty much basically setup for this).

You can see this behavior right here: https://youtu.be/2yl6UXbUGQg

I am using autolayout, Button constraints are aligned to ImageView (full size), ImageView constraints are set to Superview...

Code:

1) `UIPageViewController`:

```
class ViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    var arrPageTitle: NSArray = NSArray()
    var arrPagePhoto: NSArray = NSArray()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        arrPageTitle = ["page 1", "page 2", "page 3"]
        arrPagePhoto = ["slider-1.jpg", "slider-2.jpg", "slider-3.jpeg"]

        self.dataSource = self
        self.setViewControllers([getViewControllerAtIndex(0)] as [UIViewController],
                                direction: .Forward,
                                animated: false,
                                completion: nil)
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let pageContent: PageContentViewController = viewController as! PageContentViewController
        var index = pageContent.pageIndex
        if ((index==0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
            return nil
        }
        index -= 1
        return getViewControllerAtIndex(index)
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let pageContent: PageContentViewController = viewController as! PageContentViewController
        var index = pageContent.pageIndex
        if index == NSNotFound {
            return nil
        }
        index += 1
        if index == arrPageTitle.count {
            return nil
        }
        return getViewControllerAtIndex(index)
    }

    func getViewControllerAtIndex(index: NSInteger) -> PageContentViewController {
        let pageContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageContentViewController") as! PageContentViewController
        pageContentViewController.strTitle = "\(arrPageTitle[index])"
        pageContentViewController.strPhotoName = "\(arrPagePhoto[index])"
        pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index
        return pageContentViewController
    }
}
```

2) Content view controller, `UIViewController`:

```
class PageContentViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelTitle: UIButton!

    var pageIndex: Int = 0
    var strTitle: String!
    var strPhotoName: String!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: self.strPhotoName)
        self.labelTitle.setTitle(self.strTitle, forState: .Normal)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your image views from one view controller are spilling over to other view controllers because you need to set `clipsToBounds` to `true` on your image views. This will prevent the contents of the image view from going beyond the image view's bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Check `Clip Subviews` to prevent image view size stretched.

[image: Clip Subviews]